# wordpress links don't work after migrate in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hyperlink, migration, cpanel

I migrated a wordpress application to an apache server based on ubuntu. I can only see the home page, when clic on any link, it doesn't work. It takes to a page with the Not Found message.
I have read several forums, most of them refer to a file named .htacces and permanent links. They suggest to modify the settings on administration panel of site. My page is at '/var/www' ubuntu directory, I'm not using cpanel nor a administration panel.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add following code in your .htaccess file and check your site pages.

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```